# Upgrading router for small office

Tags: networking, router

My office is upgrading its staff and we're looking for a new router that can handle at least 12 wired computers and 4 wireless coming from 4 different rooms.  We currently manage running off a N300 from Netgear.  Can anyone recommend a decent router that will handle 15-20 computers? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

No need for a new router, just buy a 16 port gigabit (1,000mbps) unmanaged switch, connect that to the router, connect the 12 PCs to the switch.

http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&N=100010066%20600052100%20600015691%20600015696&IsNodeId=1&name=16%20x%20RJ45

Comment: Hey thanks Moab!  Not sure why the question was closed though...

Comment: They usually close shopping or buying questions, its in the faq...http://superuser.com/faq